# Use of POS.NET in .NET 4.0 WinForms application fails

Tags: c#, .net

I'am trying to implement POS.NET in my winforms application. What I'am trying to do is printing receipt from my EPSON TM-T20 receipt printer. I have successfully built an test application for printing:

```
    try
    {
        var posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
        DeviceCollection devices = posExplorer.GetDevices((DeviceCompatibilities)Enum.Parse(typeof(DeviceCompatibilities), "Opos", false));
        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = devices[0];

        var posCommon = (PosCommon)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Created instance of device: " + deviceInfo.ServiceObjectName + "\r\n");
        posCommon.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened device: " + deviceInfo.ServiceObjectName + "\r\n");
        var printer = (Microsoft.PointOfService.PosPrinter)posCommon;
        printer.Claim(1000);
        printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
        printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, text + "\x1B|1lF");
        printer.CutPaper(90);
        printer.Release();
        printer.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
    }
```

This works fine in an .NET 2.0 application. But when i copy the code to my 4.0 project it throws an exception at printer.Open();

> Exception:Caught: "Method Open threw an exception.  Could not create a service object instance, or could not get its IDispatch interface." (Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException)
>   A Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException was caught: "Method Open threw an exception.  Could not create a service object instance, or could not get its IDispatch interface."
>   Time: 05.08.2013 23:21:17
>   Thread:Main Thread[6284]

This happens even if i build a dll from my testproject and reference it in my main application as well as when i put it in a separate project running 2.0 in my solution. A webserch only came up with that this might have somthing to do with the .NET versions.

I have set supportedRuntime to 2.0.50727 in the app config, but that did nothing. Suggestions to what is wrong here is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did figure out this my self adding:

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

to my app.config did the trick!

Comment: I have same error. Windows 7 framework 3.5 and I this line doesnot helps. Even dont know what to do :(